# How to create common reusable model for all component in Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am implementing angular template and I want to implement common reusable model(pop-up). I am using bootstrap. I don't have deep knowledge of angular.
**App.component.html**

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="about">about</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="contact">contact</button>
```

**About.component.html**

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Welcome on about</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Model</button>
</div>
```

**contact.component.html**

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Welcome on contact</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Model</button>
</div>
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I want to implement common model for both component (about, contact).

Comment: Just a suggestion, try Angular Material Dialog.https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 0):

Create a model file lets say `Common-Model.ts` and place it in model folder. After that
write the model.

```
export class contactModel {
    contact : String;
    phone : int;
}
```

something similar to this as per your requirement. After that you can import this `Common-Model.ts` model file in your `contact.component.ts` file and use it as per your need.